# Converting Best Bets to Query Rules?

Tags: search, 2013

In my current SharePoint 2010 site collection I have 122 Best Bet keywords setup. I'm trying to find out how to bring them into SharePoint 2013 as Query Rules.

I read that these Best Bets are in WSS_Content database, but having imported and updated that content database to 2013, and then checking the Query Rules (in CA and the Site Collection Administration section), I cannot find any query rules based on my keyword best bets.

Failing automatic conversion, I'm trying to find good sources for information to create my own conversion script, either as C# or Powershell. Any source links out there? Having trouble finding them via google/bing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kevin,

A few resources to get you started:

In the OM, the Best Bets are exposed as a collection off individual Keywords in the [`Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.Extended.Administration.Keywords` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.search.extended.administration.keywords%28v=office.14%29.aspx):

[Keyword.BestBets Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.search.extended.administration.keywords.keyword.bestbets%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

There are some PowerShell examples of working with Best Bets here:

[Add, remove and display Best Bets for a keyword by using Windows PowerShell (FAST Search Server 2010 for SharePoint)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff191253%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

As far as adding the Query Rules in 2013 goes, this is a nice blog post that has some example PowerShell and walks you through the process:

[SharePoint 2013 - Manage Search Query Rule using Powershell](http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/sharepoint-2013-manage-search-query-rule-using-powershell)

You'll have to store the values in an intermediary format to move it between servers (CSV? XML?), but I'm sure you can figure that out.

## Edit

Ah, part of the disconnect here is that SharePoint 2013 did away with Best Bets.

Check out this blog by Pedro DeRose:

[What happened to Best Bets? Introducing Query Rules](http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2012/09/18/what-happened-to-best-bets-introducing-query-rules.aspx)

## Edit 2

Also, this page explains the new changes to working with Query Rules, but from the perspective of reading them, not creating new ones:

[What’s New In SharePoint 2013 Search (Developers Perspective) Part Three](http://sharepointfieldnotes.blogspot.com/2012/10/whats-new-in-sharepoint-2013-search.html)

You're right though about a lack of documentation on this. Digging through the OM though, there are a couple interesting classes / properties / methods that I would toy with if I were you.

[QueryRule members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.query.rules.queryrule_members.aspx)

[QueryRuleCollection.CreateQueryRule method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.query.rules.queryrulecollection.createqueryrule.aspx)

[QueryRule.CreateQueryAction method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.query.rules.queryrule.createqueryaction.aspx)

[QueryActionType enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.query.rules.queryactiontype.aspx)

I did find one questionably legitimate result on Google from a Russian news aggregator site(!?), but only on a cached version. It's a question where the poster is using the `QueryActionType` enumeration. The link to the original article has been deleted from MSDN... so... I have a screenshot from the cache:

[image: QueryActionType use]

Comment: Thanks for the comments and idea. I'd read (thoroughly) the "Manage Search Query Rule using Powershell" article, and it makes some sense, but this is a specific type of Query Rule and I'm having trouble finding the right syntax for Actions being to promote a link (the article does an ordering of results). The other link to "Add, remove and display Best Bets" is what I need for 2013 as well...

Comment: Well, that was fun. Hope that helps get you where you need to be. Learning experience for me too.

Comment: Incredibly helpful! Thank you. I'm getting to grips with most of it, but there is line that references `queryRule` (singular). It appears to be an IEnumerable (as `CreateKeywrodCondition` requires one) but I've no idea what to add here. Still, I'm looking around and am a lot further than I was :)

Comment: Glad this helped.